# Receipt Validation - Receipt maintained after app delete?

Tags: ios, receipt-validation

In the process of verifying a receipt with the app store, the receipt data is extracted from the bundle. If the user makes a purchase, deletes the app, and then reinstalls it, is the receipt still in the bundle ? Not sure how it would be.

Answer (score 2):

No, the bundle is deleted when you delete the app.

You could store your information in the keychain, on your server, or request it again from Apple (depending on the type of purchase).

Comment: Hi Wain, thanks for suggestion. If the receipt-data is stored, does it have to be refreshed from time to time, or can once extracted be used over and over again to determine the state of an auto-renewable subscription ? Also does storing that receipt data provide its own issues in terms of holding sensitive info?

Comment: No security issue I think. Not sure about the renewal, the recent should include the date

Answer (score 2):

If the app is deleted the receipt is deleted too (speaking of iOS>= 7)
Every app that you download comes with a receipt (unified receipt), so if the user delete the app and reinstall it of course will have a receipt.
If you mean purchases if they are not present the user must "restore purchases".
In my experience with auto renewable subscription I've found that even if the app is deleted if is downloaded again from the same device that originally made the purchase that will have information about old purchases.

Comment: the receipt data(base64 string( will same or differ.